# rails bundler error : Shopify_app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I listed the below
gem in my gemfile and after running "bundle install" i get the below
error.
Can someone tell me what to do, where to list or edit the correct
gems/dependencies

gem file :

gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.2'
gem 'shopify_app'

===========================

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    shopify_app x64-mingw32 was resolved to 7.0.10, which depends on
      shopify_api (~> 4.2) x64-mingw32 was resolved to 4.2.0, which
depends on
        activeresource x64-mingw32 was resolved to 2.0.1, which depends
on
          activesupport (= 2.0.1) x64-mingw32

```
rails (~> 5.0.2) x64-mingw32 was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
  activejob (= 5.0.2) x64-mingw32 was resolved to 5.0.2, which
```

depends on
        globalid (>= 0.3.6) x64-mingw32 was resolved to 0.4.0, which
depends on
          activesupport (>= 4.2.0) x64-mingw32

```
rails (~> 5.0.2) x64-mingw32 was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
  activesupport (= 5.0.2) x64-mingw32

rails (~> 5.0.2) x64-mingw32 was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
  activesupport (= 5.0.2) x64-mingw32

rails (~> 5.0.2) x64-mingw32 was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
  activesupport (= 5.0.2) x64-mingw32

rails (~> 5.0.2) x64-mingw32 was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
  activesupport (= 5.0.2) x64-mingw32

rails (~> 5.0.2) x64-mingw32 was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
  activesupport (= 5.0.2) x64-mingw32

rails (~> 5.0.2) x64-mingw32 was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
  activesupport (= 5.0.2) x64-mingw32

rails (~> 5.0.2) x64-mingw32 was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
  activesupport (= 5.0.2) x64-mingw32

rails (~> 5.0.2) x64-mingw32 was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
  actionpack (= 5.0.2) x64-mingw32 was resolved to 5.0.2, which
```

depends on
rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0) x64-mingw32 was resolved to 2.0.2, which
depends on
          activesupport (< 6.0, >= 4.2.0) x64-mingw32

```
rails (~> 5.0.2) x64-mingw32 was resolved to 5.0.2, which depends on
```

sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0) x64-mingw32 was resolved to 3.2.0, which
depends on
        activesupport (>= 4.0) x64-mingw32
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (~> 5.0.2) x64-mingw32

```
shopify_app x64-mingw32 was resolved to 0.1.0, which depends on
  rails (~> 3) x64-mingw32
```

D:\Ruby On Rails\firstRailsProject>rails s
Could not find gem 'shopify_app x64-mingw32' in any of the gem sources
listed in
 your Gemfile.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

Answer (score 0):

if you read carefuly the github readme for shopify_app, you'll find that there are some issues between ruby R versions:

so, you must do:

```
gem 'shopify_app'
gem 'activeresource', github: 'rails/activeresource'
```

for more info -> [github shoopy](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app#rails-5)